# Using or operator in rewrite rules httpd.conf

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf, friendly-url

I'm using the following rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule    ^true-stories/([0-9]+)/?$    read.php?ID=$1    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^short-stories/([0-9]+)/?$    read.php?ID=$1    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^serilaized-stories/([0-9]+)/?$    read.php?ID=$1    [NC,L]  
RewriteRule    ^poems/([0-9]+)/?$    read.php?ID=$1    [NC,L]
```

As you can see, they're all directing to the same file.

Is there any way to apply all the rules with one rule? I had problems using the "|" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule    ^/?(?:(?:true|short|serilaized)-stories|poems)/([0-9]+)/?$    read.php?ID=$1    [NC,L]
```

`(?:)` = without grouping capture in $n